# Pass controller variable to css.scss.erb file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, sass

I have a controller  `users_controller.rb` , located in `app/controllers/` . I have a file `custom.css.scss.erb`, located in `app/assets/stylesheets/`.

In the css file I want to define a variable like `$myVar: <%= @user.customisation %>`. I am getting the following output `` undefined method `customisation' for nil:NilClass ``.  What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assets (CSS/JS) are precompiled before they are being served. So you won't be able the access Controller from there.

The best you can do is, declare the dynamic css inline in the HTML before/after including the CSS.